# Why is GTM not executing my Custom HTML tag?

Tags: google-tag-manager, content-security-policy

I've been adding a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) to our website, and using nonces to allow specific scripts to run. Every expected script has executed perfectly apart from two scripts that are added by Google Tag Manager. These two scripts use the Custom HTML tag, so it makes sense they wouldn't run as GTM doesn't pass nonces to those tags (even though it passes it along to other tag types).

To get around this I added the nonce to the `<head>` element and told GTM to store it in a variable. I then created a Custom HTML tag, with the least amount of code to test, to ensure if it was working:

[image]

Strangely the script is blocked from running!

[image]

But looking in DevTools the nonce was grabbed correctly (although the attribute is missing, oddly)...

[image]

Can anyone explain why the script wasn't executed? I've tried everything I can think of. Why isn't the nonce attribute added to the `<script>` element by GTM? (Assuming that's what's happening.)

Answer (score 1):

GTM seems to [strip out some attributes](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/18040523?hl=en) before inserting custom HMTL elements.

But you can use `'<hash-algorithm>-<base64-value>'` to allow inline scripts Custom HTML tag.